# Bginfo via GPO Server 2008 r2 - Timer Not Working

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy

I am running Bginfo via GPO on Server 2008 r2 with Windows 7 clients.  The bat file (below) is run by: User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts (Logon/Logoff).

**Bat File**

> \\domain\netlogon\bginfo\bginfo.exe
>
> \\domain\netlogon\bginfo\admin.bgi /timer:0 /nolicprompt /silent

Bginfo.exe runs successfully upon logon, however, it is not silent and still has a timer countdown.  In fact, it appears to run twice.  After the first timer countdown it applies the out-of-the-box .bgi template, then it instantly opens a second time and after a second timer countdown, it applies the admin.bgi template.  I have tried /timer:00 as well with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that mangled wrapping or is that actually two lines in the batch file?  The way you describe it behaving sounds like it's two lines.

Comment: I had it on two lines. Moving it to one line fixed my issue. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer after I convert my comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but it looks from your posted batch file like you've got two lines in there.

The way you describe the batch file behaving also sounds like it's two lines.

If so, combining it on one line should fix the problem.